# How to create an index for MAX() queries in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE items(
  id       bigint primary key;
  updated  timestamp;
);
```

I would like to be able to find the most recently updated item.  The normal way I would do this is by querying:

```sql
SELECT id, updated FROM items ORDER BY updated DESC LIMIT 1;
```

However, this is slow when the table is very large (tens of millions of rows).  I was considering creating an index on the `updated` field but that would take up space and probably make inserts slower.

Partial Indexes or conditional indexes look like what I want, but I really only want the very top row.  For example, it's unclear if this would do the right thing:

```sql
CREATE INDEX items_updated ON items (updated) WHERE updated = MAX(updated);
```

Another way of expressing this is an INDEX with a LIMIT statement, where only the top N elements are included.  In my case the limit would be 1.  (not real syntax:)

```sql
CREATE INDEX items_updated ON items (updated DESC) LIMIT 1;
```

Is there a way to avoid paying the space cost of keeping an index over the entire column, avoid making inserts too slow, and optimize the query I want to make?

Comment: Just make a normal index and measure size and performance impact.

Comment: Read the docs [Create Index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createindex.html): *The expression used in the WHERE clause can refer only to columns of the underlying table, but it can use all columns, not just the ones being indexed. Presently, subqueries and aggregate expressions are also forbidden in WHERE. The same restrictions apply to index fields that are expressions.*. Not that I would see that it would make much sense as it would need to a sequence scan to get the `max` value anyway.

Comment: ".. I was considering create an index on the updated field but that would take up space and probably make inserts slower..." -- yes, will use space, and no, will barely make inserts slower.

Comment: You would probably be better off with something like: `CREATE INDEX items_updated ON items (updated desc)`. On a simple test case on my end it speed the query up by ~180 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to avoid paying the space cost of keeping an index over the entire column, avoid making inserts too slow, and optimize the query I want to make?

Unfortunately, this is impossible in general. To see why, think about how deletions would work. Let's say we have an index that does what you want - it just stores the top value or top N values in the column. Now we delete those top N rows from the table. How does our index learn the new top values? It would need to do a linear scan over the whole table. Better to store all values in a btree index.

There is a niche use case where this could possibly work. If you have a table where items are never deleted, and a column whose values are monotonically non-decreasing over time (such as "updated"), then such an index would be possible in theory, but not in Postgres. If your system has these properties, you could maintain such an index using application logic.

Similar to Adrian Klaver's comment ([How to create an index for MAX() queries in Postgres?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75771060/how-to-create-an-index-for-max-queries-in-postgres#comment133663877_75771060)), your best best most likely involves indexing every row. In order to efficiently retrieve `id` like you want, I would amend that slightly:

```
CREATE INDEX items_updated ON items (updated desc) INCLUDE (id);
```

If your system has enough usage, it may be possible to assume some condition that wouldn't hold in general. For example, we might say with near certainty that the latest item update happened in the past 6 months. If we're willing to make that assumption, then we can revise our query like so:

```
SELECT id, updated FROM items
WHERE (updated > '2022-09-01')
ORDER BY updated DESC LIMIT 1;
```

If this is the query we care about, we can exclude older items from the index like so:

```
CREATE INDEX items_updated ON items (updated DESC)
INCLUDE (id)
WHERE (updated > '2022-09-01');
```

This index can be re-created periodically using newer date thresholds to evict the older items. But there's always a chance you won't be able to find your max value efficiently, e.g. in cases where no items have been updated for 6 months, or all items from the past 6 months have been deleted.

Comment: The query needs to have the same (or more restrictive) where clause as the partial index does, or it won't use the partial index.  It looks like you tried to add that, but you just copied his original query unchanged instead.

Comment: Thanks jjanes, fixed